# Ubuntu unattended install : echo keypress to dialog

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, echo

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server 64

My unattended-mode `bootstrap.sh` script contains:

```
apt-get upgrade -y
```

I know that during execution a primitive UI for GRUB installation will be shown which requires entering keypress sequence:

```
up arrow 
space bar 
enter/return
```

Is it possible to pipe this sequence, something like:

```
echo key1 key2 key3 | apt-get upgrade -y
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tool `xdotool` to send keys to an application via the command-line like so:

```
$ xdotool key Up space Return
```

#### Example #1

Run the following command `echo` so that it's on our shell's history:

```
$ echo hi
hi
```

Now run `xdotool` with 2 up arrows to go back on the history so that we can "re-run" the previous command:

```
$ xdotool key Up Up space Return 
^[[A^[[A 
$ echo hi 
hi
$
```

#### Example #2

To send keys through a pipe you can use `xdotool type ...` to simulate the pressing of keys to an application. For example:

```
$ xdotool type ":e ~/.bashrc" | vim
```

#### References

- [xdotool main page](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)
- [xdotool man page](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml)
- [xdotool tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xdotool/)

Comment: Is it possible to pipe xdotool key-sequences to another command ?

Comment: @BaltoStar - yes. To pipe commands you'll need to use `type` instead of `key` as an argument to xdotool. See update to my answer.

Comment: Is the server installer running under X?

Comment: @slm - ok but with `type` how to specify special keys ?  `xdotool type Up space Return` ?  or somehow embed in double-quotes ?